# Security patch 8788 not patched in magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, supee-8788, magento1.9.3.1

I have recently installed 1.9.3.1 and when I run a MageReport scan, **it states that the website is still at risk and vulnerable against the 8788 patch.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MageReport checks for the following static assets that should have been removed for the SUPEE-8788 test:

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

It also checks for the following files that have been modified:

```
/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js should contain "fustyFlowFactory"
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css should contain "background:url(images/blank.gif) repeat;"
```

Feel free to report to their support page to help you figure out what went wrong when applying the patch: https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/magento-patch-supee-8788-release-1-9-3/